# How to connect virtual environment to project directory?

Tags: anaconda, spyder, anaconda3, virtual-environment

I am new to virtual environments and needed some help with a problem. I have created a virtual environment `MyEnv` using anaconda prompt. I can see the virtual environment in C:\Users\SP\anaconda3\envs. Next, I installed the python library `selenium` after activating `MyEnv` in anaconda prompt. I also created a python script file `MyScript.py` in D:\MyProject but on running the script, it gives the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`.

I installed the library using the command `conda install selenium` after activating `MyEnv` in anaconda prompt. I checked the list of packages installed in my virtual environment `MyEnv` using the command `conda list` and I could see selenium in that list. I am using spyder IDE and I launch spyder from anaconda prompt using the following commands:

`conda activate MyEnv`

`spyder`

After spyder opens, I navigate to D:\MyProject to open `MyScript.py` file.

I would greatly appreciate any help in this direction.